# Adding custom properties to junit.xml output file

Tags: android, junit4, android-espresso

I'm running Android Espresso tests using Junit4 annotations. Once finished it generates an junit.xml output file like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<testsuites tests="1" failures="0" name="UITests" time="12">
    <testsuite tests="1" failures="0" name="Test" time="232.9559440612793">
        <testcase classname="Test" name="test()" time="42.36027908325195">
        </testcase>
    </testsuite>
</testsuites>
```

However I want to be able to import my tests cases to our test case management tool. In order to do so I need to to add a property to my junit.xml file. So the end result should be like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<testsuites tests="1" failures="0" name="UITests" time="12">
    <testsuite tests="1" failures="0" name="Test" time="232.9559440612793">
        <testcase classname="Test" name="test()" time="42.36027908325195">
            <properties>
                <!-- using a custom "test_id" property -->
                <property name="test_id" value="1234567" />
            </properties>
        </testcase>
    </testsuite>
</testsuites>
```

Is there an easy way of realising this, by for instance using (custom) annotations?